# Google App Engine redirecting error

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Building kind of wiki. In the following function, I am checking if page already exist. If not it should redirect to the edit page. but it redirects infinitely, till browser stops it. '_edit'handler does nothing yet...

```
def get(self, pageName):
        p = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Pages")
        pages = p.run(batch_size = 1000)
        pageExist = False
        for page in pages:
            if pageName ==  page.pagename:
                pageExist = True
                break
        if pageExist:
            self.render_wiki(pageName, page.content)
        else:
            self.redirect('/_edit' + pageName)

PAGE_RE = r'(/(?:[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+/?)*)'
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage), ('/signup', Signup) , ('/login', Login),('/logout', Logout), (PAGE_RE, WikiPage), ('/_edit' + PAGE_RE, EditWiki)],  debug = True)
```

Comment: Funny, because I thought it was part of a URL (that's the way you are using it). More specifically I wanted to know an *example value* for `pageName`.

Comment: It **is** the part of the URL, not some RE

Comment: Not related to the question at hand, but isn't it more efficient to add `WHERE pagename = ...` to the query?

Comment: I wanted to say, it can be any string )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try moving your EditWiki route to before the WikiPage route. The PAGE_RE matches _editMyPageName so grabs it before EditWiki get a go. I'd say for each redirect your page name just gets an extra '_edit' prepended..